# Block code in lists - possible?

Tags: support, formatting

Sometimes it makes sense to write answer in points, and include couple lines of code in one point. However, indenting with 4 spaces does not work for lists, and breaking list with no-list text causes list numbering to reset. Using apostrophes ` makes all lines of code to display as one line (or separate code blocks).

Is there a good way to do it?

Example:

1. a
2. b

   first code
3. d

list break

```
second code
```

1. e
   `third code line 1
   third code line 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside lists, indent the code by `(N + 1) * 4` spaces, where `N` is the indentation level for the list item containing the code.

1. First point
2. Second point
3. Third point

   ```
   // This code is indented by 4 spaces; the item containing it is indented by 1 level.
   $account = user_load($uid);
   ```
4. Fourth point

   1. Another point
   2. Yet another one

      ```
       // This code is indented by 8 spaces; the item containing it is indented by 2 levels.
       $account = user_load($uid);
      ```